# Trying to run `compinit` on zsh but getting the error `compinit:141: parse error: condition expected: $1`

Tags: git, zsh, apple-m1, zshrc, git-completion

On m1 pro macbook using zsh, was trying to get git autocomplete to work by pasting `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` in my .zshrc however I am getting the error `compinit:141: parse error: condition expected: $1`

$FPATH is not being set in .zshrc so that shouldn't be the issue.

It's clear the problem is with compinit, since when I run just `compinit` in the shell I get the same error.

- I've tried to comb through the functions in fpath to find an issue, no luck
- Tried installing zsh-completion and setting the fpath, no luck
- Also upgraded zsh from 5.8.1 to 5.9 and manually set the fpath to the corresponding functions, no luck
- Even left the issue with `compinit` and tried `autoload -Uz vcs_info` instead, no luck

Comment: The high line number is strange. Could it be that you have your own `compinit` function, which kind of dominates the builtin one? Does it give some insight when you do a `whence -f compinit`?

Comment: The error also appears after the shell is launched with [`zsh --emulate sh`](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg00072.html). This suggests that something else in `~/.zshrc` is [setting options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663726) that are causing the issue, possibly due to an interaction with [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/10611). You may need to  rebuild`~/.zshrc` one piece at a time to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Solved

The issue was this line in my .zprofile which I thought I had to add after installing [posh-git-sh](https://github.com/lyze/posh-git-sh) (step 3) `[[ -e ~/.zshrc ]] && emulate sh -c 'source ~/.zshrc'`

Once I removed it the expected behaviour returned